# Repeated set of number and alphabets instead pivot HL values

Tags: pine-script, indicator

Hello everyone,
I am working on to make script that does look similar to elliott wave concept.So what i was planning to do is i made script based on pivot Hl.So i am trying to changed value of HL.But i get either value of Hl lables or Hl Y axis value .Instead of this i want sets of number to repeat always.Means ll means 1 then hh means 2 then hl means 3 and so on till 5 then A,B and C after finish C  i want to repeat this cycle from 1.Means From 1,2,3,4,5,A,B and C then again 1.I tried to do this with the help of tostring() function but i am unable to get desired result.Is anyone have an idea that how can i play with this.Is there any way we can make a set of this numbers and alphabets and apply on tostring() function?
I am attaching image so everyone will get an idea of what i was looking.Thanks
[ELLIOTT WAVE COUNTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfVm.jpg)

Comment: Even i am trying to put smaller wave degree count on  secondary  pivots HL that has less lookback bars period than main pivot HL.So basically two pivots one main pivot with high number of lookback period for large degree elliott count and second smaller wave degree count for small lookback bar pivots.But this will gonna need high level of coding skill as a learner i cannot thing i can make indicators looks like above chart.But ones i will get an idea how to implement then definitely i will try for smaller degree count as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integer variable to count, and use it to represent the EW count from 1 to 8.
Store the actual EW counts as a string array and reference them using the integer count.

```
var string[] ewCountStr = array.from("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "A", "B", "C")

ewCount = array.get(ewCountStr, count - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @rumpypumpydumpy again for help.I havent tried your solution yet.But i am glad that you again give me solution.You previously help me to build volume indicator and as a good gesture i published it as a open source.Indicator is https://in.tradingview.com/script/InyhrJbE-Volume-Play/ .

Comment: I tried to Do this with above code but i am getting error Undeclared identifier 'count';.Also trying to figured out how to put value in hhltxt because it has two value one is LL pivot and one is High pivot.Basically  indicator that wanna modified is Double Zig Zag with HHLL by LonesomeTheBlue.So code i get is below

Comment: thanks @rumpypumpydumpy Cannot able to post code here it showing character limit error.But you can have look in this indicator.[1]:https://in.tradingview.com/script/mRbjBGdL-Double-Zig-Zag-with-HHLL/.